# Finding SPGroup list views

Tags: 2010, list-view, groups

When I go to 'people and groups' then select a group I am looking at a list view with a few columns. Is there a way to retreive this view programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sinlge list that controls the views for all SPGroups, this list is known as the 'SiteUserInfoList'.  To get a proper collection of my data I used th following..

```
 SPUserCollection members = web.SiteGroups["name"].users;
 string str = "<Where><In><FieldRef Name='myAccount'/><Values>";
 foreach( SPUser u in members){  str+= "<Value Type='"+u.login+"'/>";

 SPQuery q = New SPQuery();
 q.Query= str+"</Values></In></Where>";
 SPList list = web.Lists["SiteUserInfoList"];
 SPListItemCollection data = list.GetItems(q);
```

To get the fields I was looking for

```
   foreach(string internalName in  list.defaultView.viewfields){
              if( ! list.Fields[internalName].hidden){
                          //keep
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The following code example uses the SiteGroups property to return the
>   collection of groups in the current site collection, and also displays
>   the name of each group.
>
> This example requires using directives for the Microsoft.SharePoint
>   and Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities namespaces.

```
using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
    {

        int IDLable = 0;
        SPGroupCollection collGroups = Web.SiteGroups;
        foreach (SPGroup oGroup in collGroups)
        {
            //list the groups
            //the code below returns each group, do what you want with it
            Label n = new Label();

            n.Text = oGroup.Name;
            n.Id = IDLable;
            this.Controls.Add(n);
            IDLable++;
        }
    }
}
```

iv ammended the above code for a custome webpart or what ever you want ;) it will produce a lable with the text of the group for each one with a unique ID for each lable

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.sitegroups.aspx